# how to optimise intersect on heroku

Tags: arrays, postgresql, heroku

I have postgresql query, where I check length of intersection of two arrays. Very simplified version of my query would look like:

```
SELECT array_length(users.array & Array[1,2,3,4]) from users;
```

It is part of larger query, but that is not important here. It works fine on my local database, but on heroku, intarray extension is not whitelisted.

I found simple function which intersect arrays, but compared to `&` operator it is rather slow.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_intersect(anyarray, anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
  SELECT ARRAY( SELECT * FROM UNNEST( $1 ) WHERE UNNEST = ANY( $2 ) );
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

On about 2000 records of my table using `&` operator takes about `50ms` and using function above takes about `150ms`. I would like to compare as many records as I can and this function just doesn't scale as well as '&' operator.

Is there any way to do it faster or to add intarray to heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess it would probably depend on the rest of your query, and how optimized it will need to be.

My first attempt would be to create a CTE of all the insecting lengths using `unnest` and `intersect`... then fetch the values from the CTE within my main expression where needed... something along the lines of:

```
WITH merged AS (
    SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) 
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[1])
) 
SELECT count(*) as length FROM merged;
```

If that was inappropriate I would have tried a function *(as you did)*, but since I was only interested in the length I would have made the function return that (to avoid needless conversion to an array and back):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_count_intersects(anyarray, anyarray)
RETURNS bigint AS $$
    SELECT count(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1) WHERE UNNEST = ANY($2)
    ) as merg;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT array_count_intersects(ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[1]);
```

If this still was not good enough, then I would look at creating an intermediate table to store/cache the lengths of the intersecting arrays that is updated via triggers when the data changes, then use this intermediate table to look up the lengths I need in my main query without the need to perform unions at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had array intersect function but I didn't think to make count function. I hoped that there will be way for using `&` operator on heroku, but I guess this is as close as I can get.